# How to retrieve blob type data while using Database change Notifier DCN

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

Getting ORA-29977 exception while executing the query

```
Stmnt.executequery("select blob_col_nme from blobtable")
```

Comment: Did you mean `blob_table`? Otherwise the sql is incorrect

Comment: Yes. Corrected thank you

Comment: Check out the LobBasicSample.java (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/BasicSamples/LobBasicSample.java) for a reference